# How to self join with condition and add a column previous?

Tags: sql, postgresql

i have this query

```
SELECT
   "os_bulan_lalu",
   "os_update"
FROM (
        SELECT
   (SELECT "OUTSTANDING" FROM tbl_nominatif_hasil 
        WHERE "BUSS_DATE"='2018-11-30' AND "COLLDET"='1') 
        as os_bulan_lalu,
   (SELECT "OUTSTANDING" FROM tbl_nominatif_hasil 
        WHERE "BUSS_DATE"='2018-12-17' AND "COLLDET"='2A')
        as os_update
   ) AS temp
```

but this query is error when i running and i want the result like

```
os_bulan_lalu | os_update

      232323 | 21424
      343242 | 432
       23432 | 23432
      234324 | 234324
      234324 | 23423423
```

i mean os_bulan_lalu is where `BUSS_DATE"='2018-11-30' AND "COLLDET"='1'`, and os_update is `"BUSS_DATE"='2018-12-17' AND "COLLDET"='2A'`

the error is

> [Err] ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

and i want the result like

```
os_bulan_lalu | os_update

      232323 | 21424
      343242 | 432
       23432 | 23432
      234324 | 234324
      234324 | 23423423
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could add your input data as formatted text.

Comment: @Tony94 the data is number like 324242141 and the table have column buss_date, and colldet for condition,,, i mean where buss_date='date' and colldet='1',,, it is possible in what i ask??

Comment: "querry is error"? Care to explain?

Comment: (SELECT "OUTSTANDING" FROM tbl_nominatif_hasil 
  WHERE "BUSS_DATE"='2018-11-30' AND "COLLDET"='1') 
  as os_bulan_lalu,
   (SELECT "OUTSTANDING" FROM tbl_nominatif_hasil 
  WHERE "BUSS_DATE"='2018-12-17' AND "COLLDET"='2A')
  as os_update
   ) AS temp

[Err] ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

Comment: @willy Please edit your question with a sample input and your expected output.

Comment: sorry the error is like in the up

Comment: @Tony94 ok i will edit

Comment: @Tony94 i updated the question

Comment: @willy You are still missing the input data

Comment: what makes the two columns (sub-queries) match or is it just random that 232323 and 21424 makes up the first row for instance?

Comment: @Tony94 that 232323 and 21424 is a dummy data dont doubt about that,  the expected result is in "BUSS_DATE"='2018-12-17' AND "COLLDET"='2A' must show the dummy data that

Comment: Was that a response to my question?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson i think yes. I guess the left column are the results of the first subquery and the right column the results of the second one.

Comment: Ok so we should assume that the order doesn't matter?

Comment: @Tony94 Ya of couse i want do that,,,,

Comment: @JoakimDanielson yes how to  the result like i want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this could work

```
SELECT A.OUTSTANDINGAS os_bulan_lalu, B.OUTSTANDINGAS os_update 
FROM (SELECT OUTSTANDING, ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY OUTSTANDING) AS row_num 
      FROM tbl_nominatif_hasil 
      WHERE BUSS_DATE = '2018-11-30' AND COLLDET = '1') AS A
JOIN (SELECT OUTSTANDING, ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY OUTSTANDING) as row_num 
      FROM tbl_nominatif_hasil 
      WHERE BUSS_DATE = '2018-12-17' AND COLLDET = '2A') AS B ON A.row_num = B.row_num
```

It assumes an equal number of rows from both queries but without knowing anything about the input it is hard to give a better answer.

*Update* If the sub-queries returns different number of rows it is better to do a `FULL OUTER JOIN` instead of a `JOIN`